# Eslint state already declared [Vuex]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, vuex

I am running ESLint and I am currently running into the following ESLint error:

> error  'state' is already declared in the upper scope  no-shadow

```
const state = {
    date: '',
    show: false
};

const getters = {
    date: state => state.date,
    show: state => state.show
};

const mutations = {
    updateDate(state, payload) {
        state.date = payload.date;
    },
    showDatePicker(state) {
        state.show = true;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations
};
```

What would be the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best way to fix would be to read the docs about the eslint "no-shadow" rule.

From this documentation, the best solution would probably be to include an exception for this one variable with the "allow" option.

You can add this with a comment to the js file to keep the exeption local:

```
/* eslint no-shadow: ["error", { "allow": ["state"] }]*/
```

Comment: and for those that get the "no-param-reassign" error, this is the solution:
    /* eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": true, "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["state"] }] */

Comment: and for those that get "getters is already declared in the upper scope...", use `/* eslint no-shadow: ["error", { "allow": ["state", "getters"] }]*/`

Answer (score 23):

The best solution is [@Linus Borg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843973/4305494).

If you are looking for an alternative, you can declare the `state` constant below the rest. This will prevent [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) because `state` will not be declared in the outer-scope yet.

Example:

```
const getters = {
    date: state => state.date,
    show: state => state.show
};

const mutations = {
    updateDate(state, payload) {
        state.date = payload.date;
    },
    showDatePicker(state) {
        state.show = true;
    }
};

const state = {
    date: '',
    show: false
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations
};
```

Answer (score 11):

If it's not too late

```
const data = {
    date: '',
    show: false
};

const getters = {
    date: state => state.date,
    show: state => state.show
};

const mutations = {
    updateDate(state, payload) {
        state.date = payload.date;
    },
    showDatePicker(state) {
        state.show = true;
    }
};

export default {
    state: data,
    getters,
    mutations
};
```

basically you define your store data as `data`, and you export it as state `state: data`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue as I was using an airbnb eslint config which is incompatible with vuex.

This worked for me, after restarting dev environment.

I created a new `.eslintrc.js` file in my store folder and added them there

```
"no-shadow": ["error", { "allow": ["state"] }],
"no-param-reassign": [
  "error",
  {
    "props": true,
    "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": [ // All properties except state are in the ignorePropertyModificationsFor array by default.
      "state",
      "acc",
      "e",
      "ctx",
      "req",
      "request",
      "res",
      "response",
      "$scope"
    ]
  }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @allochi's answer, this is what I had to do to make it work With Vue 3 which uses Vuex 4 which prefers returning a function for state:

```
// store.js

const data = {
  // ...
};

const getters = {
  // ...
};

const mutations = {
  // ...
};

const actions = {
  // ...
};

export default {
  state() { return data; },
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
};
```

If you need to import particular functions from outside, you will have to do it like this:

```
import mystore from './mystore';

const Store = createStore({
  state: mystore.state,
  getters: mystore.getters,
  mutations: mystore.mutations,
  actions: mystore.actions
});
```

I would only recommend this though if you really can't use `/* eslint no-shadow: ["error", { "allow": ["state"] }]*/`