# Mutation Payload Value Always __ob__ : Observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Hi i'm new in Vue and Javascript world, but i really want to learn this two languange.

Now i learning by watching some tutorial and i have problem. i have a Stock.vue component with this method.

```js
methods: {
        ...mapActions({ actionBuyStock: 'buyStockAction' }),
        buyStock() {
            const order = {
                stockId: this.stock.id,
                stockPrice: this.stock.price,
                quantity: this.quantity,
            };
            this.actionBuyStock(order);
            this.quantity = 0;
        },
    },
```

I use vuex and create a module to handle this. in my stocks.js module i have actions like code below

```js
const actions = {
    buyStockAction({ commit }, order) {
        commit(types.BUY_STOCK, order);
    },
};
```

and if i do console.log(order), i get the correct object as my payload.

```js
{stockId: 1, stockPrice: 110, quantity: 5}
```

but after i commit to BUY_STOCK mutation my payload (order) return **ob**: Object when i console.log(order).

```js
{__ob__: Observer}
```

this is my mutation look like

```js
const state = {...},

const mutations = {
    [types.BUY_STOCK](order) {
        console.log(order);
        // const record = state.myStocks.find((element) => element.id === order.stockId);
        // if (record) {
        //     record.quantity += order.quantity;
        // } else {
        //     state.myStocks.push({
        //         id: order.stockId,
        //         quantity: order.quantity,
        //     });
        // }
        // state.funds -= order.stockPrice * order.quantity;
    },
```

I put buyStock action in `stocks.js` and BUY_STOCK mutation in `portfolio.js`
i try to put all the action and mutation to same file but it still return **ob**: Object in mutation. can you tell me what i do wrong? i really dont want my learning phase stop here.

```js
const state = {...}

const mutations = {
        [types.BUY_STOCK](state, order) {
            console.log(order);
            // const record = state.myStocks.find((element) => element.id === order.stockId);
            // if (record) {
            //     record.quantity += order.quantity;
            // } else {
            //     state.myStocks.push({
            //         id: order.stockId,
            //         quantity: order.quantity,
            //     });
            // }
            // state.funds -= order.stockPrice * order.quantity;
        },
        
        // IF I PASSING STATE, IT WILL THROW AN LINTING ERROR (NO-SHADOW)
        // BECAUSE I ALREADY DECLARE STATE AS VARIABLE
```

[no-shadow linting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBBa9.png)

Comment: I use Vue Dev Tool, the mutation BUY_STOCK got the correct payload, but in the app it throw an error (undefined) because it cannot find **order.stockId**, **order.stockPrice**, **order.quantity**

Comment: Your mutation is incorrect. You want `[types.BUY_STOCK](state, order) { ... }`. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload. Within it, you should also use `order.stockId` instead of just `stockId`. Same for `quantity` and `stockPrice`

Comment: If i use state, it throw an error (no-shadows), because i already have `const state {}` so the linting says it dont need to pass state again, and if i still passing the state to `[types.BUY_STACK](state, order){...}` my app throw error

Comment: I don't think you read my comment correctly. `state` should be passed as the first argument to your mutation function

Comment: i do like your said `[types.BUY_STOCK](state, order) { ... }`, it throw error because i passing state

Comment: That's not what the code in your question looks like

Comment: i already delete it because it throw error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint state already declared \[Vuex\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843180/eslint-state-already-declared-vuex)

Comment: Ah now i understand, because i follow linting rule, it somehow broke my project, i start new one without linting and start using traditional way, and now it works. Too bad that this linting thing confuse me when learning. thanks @Phil

Comment: To be honest, that linting rule seems mind-numbingly stupid. I would just make sure it's disabled for your entire project since linting is typically _mostly_ useful